# Importing Package List

Tags: python, anaconda

I am attempting to import a package generated via the command:

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
```

I then attempt to create an environment using the command, as instructed [here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html), and at the top of the file generated via the command above:

```
conda create --name MyEnv --file spec-file.txt
```

However, I receive an the following PackageNotFoundError:

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels
  -ÿ\xfe
```

Comment: I can reproduce this error using Anaconda 4.3.16 with Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular Windows console, not PowerShell.  PowerShell exports files in UTF-16 / UCS-2.  See [here](https://www.kongsli.net/2012/04/20/powershell-gotchas-redirect-to-file-encodes-in-unicode/) for more.